# Windows 8.1 Pro x64 None of the Modern UI apps work, Powershell, CMD, and wsreset returns error

Tags: windows-8, powershell, modern-ui, windows-store-app

So, today somehow my pc got messed up while I wasn't home, don't ask how because i don't know *(maybe a windows update gone wrong, or ghosts were messing with it :) )* First it started with black scrn after login that I fixed it by refreshing Windows from an install media. Than I got my desktop back but all modern ui apps got messed up not even the PC Settings will start. So I looked up the problem on the internet but all of the fixes fail.

wsreset.exe quits with an error message what I can't translate to English because it doesn't makes any sense in my native language :( *(poor windows translation)*

Than the `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml` command fails with this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -Di
sableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, The package can't be registered.
An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/f
wlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 1f01eb1f-b06a-0002-6ded
-011f6ab0d001 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID
1f01eb1f-b06a-0002-6ded-011f6ab0d001
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\Ap
pxM ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\WINDOWS\WinStore\AppxManifest.xm
   l:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageMa
   nager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

This `((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\InboxApplications") | Get-ItemProperty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode` Powershell command fails with this error:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, The package can't be registered.
An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing
 app deployment issues.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 1f01eb1f-b06a-0000-0cee-011f6ab0d001 in the Event Log or use th
e command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID 1f01eb1f-b06a-0000-0cee-011f6ab0d001
At line:1 char:134
+ ... operty).Path | Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\vpnp...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

The most annoying thing is, that I can't create a new local user to check out if the problem is global or user related because you need the modern ui settings app for that.

I checked the folder/file/registry permissions and all seems to be in order, but the error message couldn't be more specific than this "WriteError"

Now I'm stuck. I have no clue what to do next. What I know is that I don't want to do a clean Windows install.

Is there anything I can try to fix this problem?

Comment: So.. not to be rude, but... your PC was messed up, and you decided to try running some random PowerShell command?

Comment: Thats not random, those commands are form MS TechNet and they suppose to repair the store app and all modern ui apps. And as I wrote I did a refresh install or what ever it's called which fixed the black scrn error but did mess up modern ui apps. Now I added a new local user from command line and for that user all the apps are working properly. At least now I know that the problem is in my user account.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user on the command line? Open an cmd.exe as administrator and type: `net user newusername /add`

Answer (score 1):

This script fix registry premissions for appx installer and can help
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Re-registers-Modern-Appx-2e528428#content

> Description from page:
>
> Re-registers Modern Appx packages that won't launch due to registry
>   permissions
>
> This script is designed to fix Modern (Windows 8.x) apps that will not
>   launch and cannot be re-registered due to a permission error with a
>   specific registry key. There are multiple examples of this error on
>   answers.microsoft.com."
>
> Script name: ModernAppRegFix.ps1

It's look like script take keys from

```
HKCU:Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\
```

and reset ownership to user `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` for subkeys in section with name ending `\PSR`. After fixing permissions script register applications.